# Force `Simplify` to use half angle identities?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

How do I force `Simplify` to use half angle identities?

Suppose I have (x is in the `Reals`)

```
f = ArcTan[1/x^2];
expr = Cos[f/2];
```

notice that

```
Cos[f] == 1/Sqrt[1 + 1/x^4]
```

> `True`

and using the half-angle identity $$\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\vartheta}{2}}$$

we can write (I only need the positive root; `expr>0` for all real `x`):

```
FullSimplify[expr == Sqrt[(1 + Cos[f])/2]]
```

> `True`

How can I get `Simplify[expr]` to output `Sqrt[(1 + Cos[f])/2]` (with f expanded out) instead of `Cos[1/2 ArcTan[1/x^2]]`?

My suspicion is that this is because the `LeafCount` of `Sqrt[(1 + Cos[f])/2]` (with `f` expanded out) would be higher than `Cos[1/2 ArcTan[1/x^2]]`. Is there maybe a way to modify the `ComplexityFunction` so that it is rewarded for using these half angle formulas?

Right now I am doing the half-angle substitutions with functions I wrote and replacement rules, but I'd rather `Simplify` just do it for me.

**Add-on**

Maybe it's not relevant, but I probably should've at least posted the replacement rule I am doing for now so others can see it. I have a long formula `compEx` and I find everywhere that I see something like `Cos[1/2___`(*something*)`]`, and there I use the half angle formula for cosine:

```
fun = ArcTan[(1 - x)/Sqrt[-I - x^2]]/Sqrt[-I - x^2];
compEx = 
 Simplify[ComplexExpand[Re[fun], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], 
  1/2 < x < 1];

halfAngleCos[k_] = Sqrt[(1 + Cos[2 k])/2];
subbed = compEx /. Cos[1/2 k__] -> halfAngleCos[1/2 k];
```

I do the same thing with half angle formula for `Sin` also.

Comment: why not use Replace intead of Simplify? As in `expr=Cos[f/2]; expr/.Cos[x_/2]:> Sqrt[(1+Cos[x])/2]` ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkawb.png) or do you need to use Simplify only?

Comment: @Nasser I am doing pretty much that (I added what I'm currently doing to the bottom), but I got stuck up on wanting `Simplify` to do it for me. Now that I think about it though, the way I'm doing it is pretty clean. So maybe I shouldn't worry about how to do this with `Simplify`?

Comment: The part that annoyed me was just that I had to write out the half-angle formulas :(
But I am slow typer, need to work on my typing skills (home keys!!!)

Comment: sometimes making your own transformation rules and using them explicitly on expressions using Replace or ReplaceAll or Cases,  is simpler than teaching Simplify to use them. But I am sure this can be done using Simplify, but need to adjust also the complexity function I think.

Comment: You cannot force the half angle formula to be applied, because they are not True. The same problem arises with TrigToExp. You get sums of Log functions, that have to combined into logs of products.  As a rule, all these identities imply equality of square roots. So its often simpler to Simplify the equality of their squares, because thats the goal. The complex phases of the root expression in  these identities have to be tabulated by hand or a complex Arg Plot, normally.

Comment: @RolandF ah yes I see thanks. This makes sense to use the squares for these identities. Sorry I didn't see this comment at the time it was posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let `FullSimplify` know that you *really* don't like trigonometric functions in your output by providing a custom `ComplexityFunction` with a large weight on unwanted function(s).

```
FullSimplify[expr, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 50 Count[#, Cos[_], All] &)]
(* Sqrt[1 + 1/Sqrt[1 + 1/x^4]]/Sqrt[2] *)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was scratching my head a little with the [documentation examples](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) in ComplexityFunction, but this makes sense now